# File access error programming in Delphi 7 using ReWrite(f)

Tags: delphi-7

Spent 2 hours looking at similar issues and used IsFileInUse, and sure enough it is in use. It loads a jpg image using MapObjectsLt and though I do understand a little of file locking, this software worked perfectly under Windows 7, which we used at work. Now I have moved to Windows 10 on a new laptop, and it only now gives an error. Myself and windows explorer are the only users I am aware of so no one else has that small text file which positions the image when open. I think the difference lies in Windows. I used ProcExp.exe to look at the processes that might be locking/using that file and it could not find that small 6 line file. I changed my code and first unloaded the image before changing the jgw/text file, after which it reloads and is repositioned. If MapObjectsLt locked the file and Windows 7 allowed the change?? Do I change this in code somehow ie force the removal of a handle knowing no one that matters is using the file??

```
    procedure SaveWorldFile(FileName:TFileName);
    var f:TextFile; i:Integer; Ext:String[4]; ImageFile:TFileName;
    begin
      ImageFile:=FileName;
      if Pos('.SID',UpperCase(FileName))<>0 then Ext:='.sdw' else
      if Pos('.JPG',UpperCase(FileName))<>0 then Ext:='.jgw' else Ext:='.tfw';
      FileName:=ChangeFileExt(FileName,Ext);

      //tried to close the handle in this function..because
      //I believe at this point I am the only one using this file.
      //Did not work but was part of my hunt for a solution
      //I used for a different reason but found on this site
      IsFileInUse(FileName);

      //This section worked before and last line reloads the image
      //The image is "untouched" only its position changes
      //This worked under Windows 7 now Windows 10 does not
      AssignFile(f,FileName);
      ReWrite(f); //error under Windows 10
      for i:=1 to 6 do WriteLn(f,P[i]:0:8);
      CloseFile(f);

      //Now reload the image
      frmWRM.AddImageLayer(ImageFile);
    end;
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please describe your issue more concisely so others can comprehend what you already did and what exactly your problem is. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for advice how to improve your question.

Comment: it would help if you would post the code and exception you are getting

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution on your site, after hours of following what I thought was a Windows 10 error. It was the permissions on files copied to a hard drive. Once changed my software was working as per normal. Thanks for the hint from your site.